# Асинхронный вызов

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, telethon

Я использую библиотеку *telethon* для работы с Telegram. Я получаю сообщение следующим образом:

```
while True:

    message = await client.get_messages(dp, 100, offset_id=offset_mes)

    for i in message:
        all_message.append(i.to_dict())
```

Так как метод get_messages асинхронный следующие действия не дожидаются его завершения и это очень сильно мешает мне.
Как бы я мог дождаться его выполнения?

Comment: Ну вообще `await` как-раз и должен ждать результата. Хотя в питоне всё хитро, наверное зависит от того, как вы этот код вообще вызываете

Comment: Вы уверены, что ```get_messages``` что-то возвращает? Исходя из вашего вопроса и примера кода - скорее всего так и есть.